# Prevent Proxyman from capture HTTP/HTTPS requests

Tags: ios, swift

It is possible to prevent Proxyman from capture HTTP/HTTPS requests and responses data?

I am afraid that the information and responses that Proxyman show can be used by malicious programmers

Comment: [Security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity?wprov=sfti1) is not security.  You can use certificate pinning to try avoid MITM but your design should be such that it doesn't matter if the payload is intercepted.

Comment: How to use Proxyman is arguably not a programming question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.